# Bit manipulation and masking in c

Tags: c, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am working on some c problems. I have one process that needs to be executed and has bit manipulations. I have 2 variables with uint8 type say `uint8 bit_Part1` & `uint8 bit_Part2` (U8 each). I want to add values to these variables having values one is `U4` and other `U6` like `U4_part1` and `U6_part2` and one boolean value `Bool_Part3` I want to place them into these `uint8 bit_Part1` & `uint8 bit_Part2` structure as below

[image]

So far i tried shifting like:

Its psudo code:

```
uint8 bitman_u8_part1 =0;
    uint8 bitman_u8_part2 =0;
    bitman_u8_part1 |= ((uint8)(U4_Part1));  // 0000\\\\ 
    bitman_u8_part1 | = ((uint8)((U6_Part2 >> 2)<<4));// append 0000 for the empty 
    bitman_u8_part2 | =((uint8)(EC2_TCH_BITMAP_U6_Part2<<4));
    bitman_u8_part2 | =((bool)BOOL_Part3 & 1<<4);
```

Here is an example of what I expect to see:

If U4_part1=0111, U6_Part2=001111, Bool_Part3=1(true)

then the expected result is:
bit_Part1 & uint8 bit_Part2 both will contain data -> 00000|1|00||1111|0111

(note I have added | just for separation between data || is for separation of uint8 bit_Part1 & uint8 bit_Part2).

Additional values are in uint8 bit_Part2 are filled with 0, compare with picture above (& U4 means value with 4 bits U6 as in with value with 6 bits)

How can i do it?

> UPDATE:

Something that i have tried again :

```
 unsigned int U4_data1 = 12;    /* 60 = 0000 1100 */  
   unsigned int U6_data2 = 53;  /* 21 = 0011 0101 */
   unsigned int Bool_data3 =1;
   unsigned int U8_part1 =0;
   unsigned int U8_part2 = 0;
   U8_part1 = U4_data1;
   U8_part1 |= (U6_data2<<4);
   printbinary(U8_part1);
   U8_part2 |= U6_data2>>4;
   U8_part2 |= (Bool_data3)<<2;
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of input values and the expected output values?

Comment: What are the typedef for these "U4" etc types? Why aren't you using standard C types from `stdint.h`?

Comment: Expected output: e.g. U4_part1=0111, U6_Part2=001111, Bool_Part3=1(true) expected op-> as uint8 bit_Part1 & uint8 bit_Part2 both will contain data -> 00000|1|00||1111|01111 .... note I have added | just for separation between data || is for separation of uint8 bit_Part1 & uint8 bit_Part2. Additional values are in uint8 bit_Part2 are filled with 0, compare with picture above (& U4 means value wiith 4 bits U6 as in with value with 6 bits)

Comment: Put clarifying information in the question, not in comments.

Comment: In your expected output, it appeas that bit_part1 is 111101111.  Did you perhaps mean 11110111?

Comment: @Basya yes. its 11110111 (not sure why but cant edit my comment) added description in question.

Comment: Comments can only be edited for five minutes.  Putting the information in the question itself is more important anyway.

Comment: Have you had success with any of the proposed answers?  If not, please give us some more information (at the very least, #defines and declarations of anything used in your code snippet.  Preferably, a minimal, reproduceable example (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Three people have proposed solutions for you.  Have you tried any of them?  Do you understand them or do you need more explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assemble the pieces in a temporary object:
uint16_t temp =   Bool_Part3 << 10
                | U6_part2   <<  4
                | U4_part1   <<  0;

// Redivide the temporary object into the destination parts:
uint8_t bit_Part1 = temp >> 0;
uint8_t bit_Part2 = temp >> 8;
```

If `Bool_Part3` has some integer type that you are calling Boolean even though it is not a standard `_Bool` or `bool` (declared in `<stdbool.h>`) type and may have a value other than 0 or 1, then an appropriate way to ensure 0 or 1 is inserted in the result is to cast it to `_Bool`, as with:

```
uint16_t temp = (_Bool) Bool_Part3 << 10 …
```

While you can use other idioms, such as `!!Bool_Part3`, the cast has the advantage of explicitly expressing the desired operation, a conversion to 0 or 1. (While programmers 30 years ago had to use various workarounds in C, there is no reason to program kludges the way people did decades ago when modern expressions are available.)

Notes:

- `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` are declared in `<stdint.h>`.
- Shifts by zero are shown for illustration and uniformity. They may be omitted.

Comment: A bool in C is just an integer.  A 'true' value could be, for example, 0xFFFE.  So ORing in Bool_Part3, even with the shift, might not set the correct bit, and might affect other, higher, bits.

Comment: @Basya: A `bool` in C (as declared in `<stdbool.h>`) is a `_Bool`, and storing any value in a `_Bool` type converts it to that type, which, per C 2018 6.3.1.2, results in 0 or 1.

Comment: I have worked in too many environments where that was actually not the case, to suggest relying on it without qualification.  And the questioner does not specify the type of BOOL_Part3, it could be an old Windows BOOL for all you know (typedef int BOOL;)  There is plenty of C code out there, in current use, which relies on integer booleans.

Comment: Since the OP did not specify his types, and since the code you wrote could fail in many environments, I disagree with you.   Also, since votes are anonymous, on what do you base your comment?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
#define LOW_4_MASK 0xF
#define LOW_2_MASK 3
#define BOOL_PART3_BIT = 1 << 2;

bit_Part1 = (U4_Part1 & LOW_4_MASK) | ((U6_part2 & LOW_4_MASK) << 4);
bit_Part2 = (U6_part2 >> 4) & LOW_2_MASK;

if (Bool_Part3)
    bit_Part2 |= BOOL_PART3_BIT;
```

I don't know the types of all your variables here, or whether there exists the possibility of having other bits set, outside the six bit range of `U6_part2`, for example.  The masking prevents stray bits, set in error, from propagating into your resulting `bit_Part1` and `bit_Part2` variables.

I handled the boolean separately because a boolean in much C code including your excerpt as written, is an integer (only newer C standard have modified this, and much C code does not use the newer bool definitions); any non-zero value counts as "true".  If you come into this piece of code with `Bool_Part3` set to, for example, 0xFFF0, you certainly do not want to OR it into your result. Even if you mask it to the lowest bit, you may not get the correct result.

Comment: It is incorrect to state “a boolean in C is an integer” (meaning may have values other than 0 or 1). Per C 2018 6.3.1.2 and the rules for assignment and initialization, storing a value in a `bool` (as defined by `<stdbool.h>`) or ` _Bool` converts it to 0 or 1. C has never had a Boolean type that could represent other values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I modified my wording to indicate that this is true in much, but not all, C code.

Comment: The fact that OP isn't using `uint8_t` means he's not using `<stdint.h>`, which probably means he's not using `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @yhyrcanus - true.  And what does that imply for the solution I proposed?  I am not suggesting relying on <stdbool.h>, nor does my solution fail if he chooses to use <stdbool.h>.

Comment: I agree with everything you wrote. I'm affirming that the way you did it is probably the safest and easiest to understand (although I probably would have just done ` | ( Bool_Part3 != 0 ) << 2` instead of the extra line; personal preference).

Comment: @yhyrcanus - thanks.  Yes, there are several ways to handle that 'bool'.  A double-not might do it also.  I wanted to make it as easy to read and understand as possible, but there is definitely room for personal preference/style in how to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another method using union. Just replace 1 with your boolean variable, 15 with U6 and 7 with U4.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    struct st_bitman_u8 {
        unsigned char part1;
        unsigned char part2;
    }bitman_u8;
    
    union Data {
        short sum;
        struct st_bitman_u8 _bitman_u8;
    }data;
    
   
    short sum1 = 1 << 10; //1 is Bool_Part3
    short sum2 = 15 << 4; //15 is U6_Part2
    short sum3 = 7;       //7 is U4_part1
   
    data.sum = sum1+sum2+sum3;
    
    printf("part1 %d part2 %d",data._bitman_u8.part1, data._bitman_u8.part2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only bitManipulation & masking is required. Its easier with struct but its not required here. Only shifting masking operations are needed

Comment: Using a union does not guarantee the desired results since different C implementations may have different byte ordering in a `short`.

Comment: @ShubhamKhare This solution is not the best one but it is a new simple way for your problem. It's up to you to select a simple solution or another one.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is just a solution based on my compiler byte ordering. A programmer can change this code when there is Big Endian or Little Endian ordering.